# Python Itertools on two lists. Get more then 1 value from each list

Tags: python, list, permutation, python-itertools

I have the code below. This code gives all possible combinations between list1 and list2.

```
import itertools
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = [6,7,8,9,10]
print(list(itertools.product(list1, list2)))

Output:
[(1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8), (1, 9), (1, 10), (2, 6), (2, 7), (2, 8), (2, 9), (2, 10), (3, 6), (3, 7), (3, 8), (3, 9), (3, 10), (4, 6), (4, 7), (4, 8), (4, 9), (4, 10), (5, 6), (5, 7), (5, 8), (5, 9), (5, 10)]
```

What I want is to get all possible combinations of 2 values each from list1 and 3 values from list2 (without duplicates). So possible output should as below. How can I do this?

```
[(1,2,6,7,8), (1,2,7,8,9), (1,2,8,9,10), (2,3,6,7,8), and so on.......]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will do:

```
from itertools import combinations as com, product as prod

list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

[c1 + c2 for c1, c2 in prod(com(list1, 2), com(list2, 3))]

# [(1, 2, 6, 7, 8), 
#  (1, 2, 6, 7, 9), 
#  (1, 2, 6, 7, 10),
#  ...
#  (4, 5, 7, 9, 10), 
#  (4, 5, 8, 9, 10)]
```

This makes the cartesian product of the respective combinations from the two lists and simply concatenates each pair to avoid nested tuples.

Comment: Ty for your answer. Is a cartesian product with or without duplicates?

Comment: Well, in set theory, no. In Python, however, if there are duplicates in one of the pools (which can be any iterables), there will be duplicates in the product.

Answer (score 0):

You need first to build the combinations you need for each list, then do the product, you'll also need to join the inner result of product `((1, 2), (6, 7, 8)) => (1, 2, 6, 7, 8)`

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

c1 = combinations(list1, r=2)
c2 = combinations(list2, r=3)

print(list(map(lambda x: tuple(chain(*x)), product(c1, c2)))) # [(1, 2, 6, 7, 8), (1, 2, 6, 7, 9), (1, 2, 6, 7, 10), (1, 2, 6, 8, 9), (1, 2, 6, 8, 10), (1, 2, 6, 9, 10), (1, 2, 7
```